# How to share a custom Arcmap .mxd and toolbar?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, arctoolbox, toolbar

Using Arc 10.3.1, I created two tools (via Modelbuilder) which are in their own toolbox.

I then created a new Arcmap toolbar, named "Wetland Rating", and added the two tools, each with their own buttons, to that toolbar.  The toolbar is to be used in conjunction with a purpose-built .mxd.  Please see the two following images:

[image]

[image]

The .mxd and toolbox are stored on my organization's network path/folder.  Everything works fine when I load the .mxd and use the tool buttons.

However, other users in the organization need to access this .mxd and its toolbar buttons.  Here's the problem: when those users load the mxd, its layers display correctly, but my toolbar and its buttons do not appear.  The .mxd is useless without the associated toolbar.  How can I share this .mxd/toolbar with other users?

Comment: Have you seen this. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/get-started/customizing-the-ui/saving-your-customizations-in-a-document.htm

Comment: Perfect, if you want to post your response as an answer, I'd be happy to check it off.

Comment: Sure, I research some more and then post.

Comment: It looks like you are saving your customisation to your normal template which is specific to your login on your machine. You need to be saving your customisation into the MXD itself. The link that @Deepank has given shows you how to save customisation to the MXD itself. Note you would need to change this again if you wanted to do new customisation in a new MXD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to save your working content on Arcmap such as geodatabases (*.gdb), *.mxd and map packages (*.mpk). *gdb and *mpk formats are widely used for working in groups or transferring complete data within teams. But unfortunately they do not store your customizations on creation of shortcut keys, changing toolbar menu content etc.

For that purpose Arcmap provides the [excellent guide](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/get-started/customizing-the-ui/saving-your-customizations-in-a-document.htm) to save these small customizations.